# What is the replacement for Hibernate's Transaction.wasCommitted method?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to update some code from an old version of Hibernate (version 3). It uses two methods of the `Transaction` interface that no longer exist in Hibernate 5.

```
session.getTransaction().wasCommitted()
session.getTransaction().wasRolledBack()
```

What is the equivalent in Hibernate 5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `session.getTransaction().getStatus()`.  For example,

```
session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.COMMITTED
session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK
```

You may also want to examine [the docs of TransactionStatus](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/transaction/spi/TransactionStatus.html) to see the relatively fine granularity of transaction statuses, as you might either want or need more inclusive substitutes than those above.  Also, don't overlook `TransactionStatus`'s methods, which you may find helpful.  For example,

```
session.getTransaction().getStatus().isOneOf(
        TransactionStatus.MARKED_ROLLBACK,
        TransactionStatus.ROLLING_BACK,
        TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue when upgrading hibernate. This is how I modified my code

```
Transaction trans = null;
```

Once we commit the transaction we can check its status and return Boolean value as true or false as

```
  boolean wasCommitted=trans.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")?true:false;
```

We might get confused between Active and COMMITTED but I found that active in hibernate is eqivalent to wasCommitted() in previous version

```
ACTIVE,
    /**
     * The transaction has been completed successfully.
     */
    COMMITTED,
    /**
     * The transaction has been rolled back.
     */
    ROLLED_BACK,
    /**
     * The transaction has been marked for rollback only.
     */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
transaction.getStatus().canRollback()
```